# Find a Row that contains a partial text value, return the row number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple VBA function that will return the first row from a range on a separate sheet that contains a text value, but may not be an exact 1 for 1 match.  for example:   'Farm' is found in 'Farm123'

My attempt was:

```
Public Function Locit(whatcell As Range) As Range
  Set Locit = Sheets(Sheet4).Columns("C").Find(what:="*" & whatcell.Value & "*", lookat:=xlPart)
End Function
```

Needless to say, it failed and it has been years since I have attempted this type of code.  Can someone set me on the right track?

Comment: If this function is being called from a worksheet cell, you might want to return the **address** of the range rather than the range itself.

Comment: FYI, you can use built-in functions for this. Barry Houdini has many fine answers about using the `LOOKUP` function for similar tasks.

Answer (score 0):

here your updated variant

```
Public Function Locit(whatcell As Range)
    Locit = Sheets("Sheet4").[C:C].Find(whatcell.Value).Row
End Function
```

but better this variant, i guess:

```
Public Function Locit(whatcell As Range, whatrange As Range)
    Locit = whatrange.Find(whatcell.Value).Row
End Function
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the find value in but could easily provide additional functionality by passing in the range to search and what property to return.

```
Public Function Locit(whatCell As Range, whatColumn As Range, Optional iTYP As Long = 1)
    With whatColumn
        Select Case iTYP
            Case 1   'return row number
                If CBool(Len(whatCell.Value)) Then _
                    If Application.CountIf(.Cells, Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42)) Then _
                        Locit = Application.Match(Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42), .Cells, 0)
            Case 2   'return cell as range
                If CBool(Len(whatCell.Value)) Then _
                    If Application.CountIf(.Cells, Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42)) Then _
                        Set Locit = Application.Index(.Cells, Application.Match(Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42), .Cells, 0))
            Case 3   'return cell as address
                If CBool(Len(whatCell.Value)) Then _
                    If Application.CountIf(.Cells, Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42)) Then _
                        Locit = Application.Index(.Cells, Application.Match(Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42), .Cells, 0)).Address(0, 0)
            Case 4   'return value
                If CBool(Len(whatCell.Value)) Then _
                    If Application.CountIf(.Cells, Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42)) Then _
                        Locit = .Cells(Application.Match(Chr(42) & whatCell.Value & Chr(42), .Cells, 0)).Value
        End Select
    End With
End Function
```

A range of cells is sufficient; you do not need to pass along the worksheet as well unless you do it as part of the range. For example, with *farm* in A1 then:

```
=Locit(A1, Sheet4!C:C)
```

By default, this actually returns the row which seems to be what you are looking for. If *Farm123* was in Sheet4's C4 then it would return 4. Using the optional **iTYP** parameter yields additional information.

```
=Locit(A1, Sheet4!C:C, 1)           ◄ returns row number (default)
=Locit(A1, Sheet4!C:C, 2)           ◄ returns C4 as a cell range (probably displays "Farm123" just as if you used =Sheet4!C4)
=Locit(A1, Sheet4!C:C, 3)           ◄ returns "C4" as a string
=Locit(A1, Sheet4!C:C, 4)           ◄ returns "Farm123" as a string
```

I'm a little unclear on why an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and/or [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) is not appropriate.